customization parameters
I am trying to create a custom PWM generation IP. I want to have the bit width of the counter I am using in my code as a generic but dependent on two other parameters.
So, I defined three generics in my code:
    BIT_WIDTH          : integer := 32;
    SystemClock        : integer := 100000000;
    PWMClock           : integer := 1000

and in the IP packager in Vivado I made the setting as this window for the Bit_Width parameter:
and in my VHDL code, I used BIT_WIDTH every where I needed it. I expect the BIT_WIDTH to change regarding to the dependency expression:

expr ceil([expr {log($SystemClock/$PWMClock)/[expr log(2)]}])

But this doesn't seem to work and when I change the two other parameters, I get the error:
ERROR: [Common 17-170] Unknown option '-Inf', please type 'set_property -help' for usage info.
It seems like I am missing something here.
Do I need to bring the expression somehow in my VHDL code too?

The constants in the question are:
    SystemClock        : integer := 100000000;
    PWMClock           : integer := 1000;

And the expression used is:
expr ceil([expr {log($PWMClock/$SystemClock)/[expr log(2)]}])

Since SystemClock and PWMClock are integers, the result of $PWMClock/$SystemClock will be zero which means will try and take the log of zero which would explain the result of -Inf which is not valid for a bit-width.
As a minimum I think the expression used should be:
expr ceil([expr {log($SystemClock/$PWMClock)/[expr log(2)]}])

I.e. swap the order of $SystemClock and $PWMClock in the division. The above should result in 17, which is the expected answer.
As pointed out in a comment from greybeard, to allow for SystemClock and PWMClock not being integer multiples adding casts to perform the division as floating point would be more robust. E.g.:
expr ceil([expr {log([expr double($SystemClock)]/[expr double ($PWMClock)])/[expr log(2)]}])

I say should since haven't created a project in Viavado to prove it.

(Maybe computation of log's argument should be forced to a decent floating point format - then again, that would have masked this error.)
